# rails before_save callback for new record only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I would like to use my `before_save` call back only the first time. (When my activerecord is being saved for the first time. How do I do that?

Currently in my callback I'm checking for attributes for .nil? before writing them.

The purpose of this callback is to initialize an attribute from a value retrieved from an associated model.

Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `before_create` callback instead.

Comment: it's deprecated